# SSL on domain-A on set folders else domain-B for everything else

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am setting up a new site and am using 2 domains for the site, one is domain-A.com which has a SSL/HTTPS cert on it and domain-B.co.uk

I want all visitors to go to domain-B.co.uk, then when they go to the portal, billing etc... go to https://www.domain-A.com/portal/FILENAME.php

Then when they leave https://www.domain-A.com/portal/ change the domain back to http://domain-B.co.uk/FILENAME.php

So basically using domain-A for set forums that I want SSL on, anything else use domain-B.

I am not sure how to do this, any help please?

Thanks,
Garry

Comment: do both these domains share the same document root?

Comment: Yes domain-A.com is the main domain and domain-B is parked on top, it was an after thought to get domain-B after I got the SSL cert, and I can't really afford to get another SSL and have the host change the domain for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if the request is for domain-A and not for /portal/, redirect to domain-B
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-A\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain-B.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# if the request is for domain-B and for /portal, redirect to SSL domain-A
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-B\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?portal/(.*)$ https://domain-A.com/portal/$1 [L,R=301]
```